# Recursive entry to executependingtransactions in onStart() of activity of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a very stupid problem. App has a lot of children fragments into base fragment. And when you lock screen in landscape mode, waiting ~5-6 seconds and turn on screen, app crahes with "Recursive entry to executependingtransactions". And it is repeat only by this scenario. It doesn't repeat when user rotate screen or lock screen in portrait mode. I think that problem appears, because when you lock screen in landscape mode and after turn on it, app appear in <~1sec in portrait mode and immediately trying to rotate. Any ideas?

 Full exception :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.customertrax/com.customertrax.activities.entities.CustomEntityActivityExt}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1957)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1982)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3390)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1152)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4463)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:529)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1461)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1807)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:977)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1922)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1816)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:977)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1922)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:565)
                                                                  at com.customertrax.activities.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:78)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1930)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1982) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3390) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:123) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1152) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4463) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:529) 
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code from BaseActivity. There are nothing special. It extends form ActionBarActivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}
```

Comment: please provide some code of the `BaseActivity.onStart` method, since that is where the crash occurs.

Comment: @Matthijs updated question